Android: The app doesn't upload file to firebase
I have a problem. Android application upload the audio file to firebase, but the application doesn't upload the content.
I have these codes:
UploadSong (this code the controller of the input:
public class UploadSong extends AppCompatActivity {
    private FirebaseUser user;
    private ActivityResultLauncher<String> audioPickerLauncher;
    private String filePath;

    private TextView TVfilePathShow;
    private EditText ETSongAuthor;
    private EditText ETSongTitle;

    private FirebaseFirestore songDB;
    private CollectionReference songRef;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        user= FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        if (user != null && getIntent().getIntExtra("upload",1)==1){
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            EdgeToEdge.enable(this);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_upload_song);
            audioPickerLauncher = registerForActivityResult(new AudioPickerContract(), this::onAudioFileSelected);
            TVfilePathShow = findViewById(R.id.songURL);
            ETSongAuthor = findViewById(R.id.songAuthor);
            ETSongTitle = findViewById(R.id.songTitle);
            songDB=FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
            songRef = songDB.collection("Songs");
            ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main), (v, insets) -> {
                Insets systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars());
                v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom);
                return insets;
            });
        }
        else if(user != null){
            finish();
            Intent openList = new Intent(this, MainPageAfterLoggedIn.class);
            startActivity(openList);
        }
        else {
            finish();
            Intent openLogin = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(openLogin);
        }

    }

    public void selectFile(View view) {
        audioPickerLauncher.launch("audio/*");
    }
    @SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
    private void onAudioFileSelected(Uri selectedAudioUri){
        filePath = selectedAudioUri.getPath();
        TVfilePathShow.setText(filePath);
        TVfilePathShow.setTextColor(R.color.black);

    }

    @SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
    public void upload(View view) {
        if (filePath == null){
            TVfilePathShow.setText("Adj meg egy fajlt!");
            TVfilePathShow.setTextColor(R.color.red);
        }
        else {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, UploadService.class);
            intent.putExtra("fileUri", filePath);
            //TODO: Megformazni jora a fileformatumot.
            String songAuthor = ETSongAuthor.getText().toString();
            String songTitle = ETSongTitle.getText().toString();
            String[] filePathParts = filePath.split("/");
            songRef.add(new song(songTitle,songAuthor,filePathParts[filePathParts.length-1]+"audio", user.getEmail()))
                    .addOnSuccessListener(documentReference -> {
                        Log.i(UploadSong.class.getName(),"Letrehozva");
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(documentReference -> {
                        Log.e(UploadSong.class.getName(),"Error");
                    });
            startService(intent);
            finish();
            Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, MainPageAfterLoggedIn.class);
            startActivity(intent2);
        }

    }
}

AudioPickerContract:
public class AudioPickerContract extends ActivityResultContract<String, Uri> {
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Intent createIntent(@NonNull Context context, String s) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        intent.setType(s);
        return intent;
    }

    @Override
    public Uri parseResult(int i, @Nullable Intent intent) {
        if (intent == null || i != RESULT_OK) {
            return null;
        }

        return intent.getData();
    }
}


UploadService:
public class UploadService extends Service {
    private static final String TAG = "UploadService";
    private StorageReference storageRef;
    private static final String CHANNEL_ID = "UploadServiceChannel";
    @Override
    public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();
        storageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
    }

    @SuppressLint("ForegroundServiceType")
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        String fileUri = intent.getStringExtra("fileUri");
        if (fileUri != null) {
            String[] fileUriParts = fileUri.split(":");
            Uri contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            ContentResolver cR = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver();
            Uri realFileUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(contentUri,fileUriParts[1]);
            startForeground(1,createNotification());
            File file = new File(String.valueOf(realFileUri));
            Log.i(TAG,String.valueOf(file.length()));
            Log.i(TAG,realFileUri.toString());
            uploadFile(realFileUri);
        }
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    private void uploadFile(Uri fileUri) {
        StorageReference songsRef = storageRef.child("songs");
        String[] fileUriParts = fileUri.toString().split("/");
        StorageReference fileRef = songsRef.child(fileUriParts[fileUriParts.length-1]+".mp3");
        Log.i(TAG,fileRef.toString());
        ContentResolver cR = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver();
        StorageMetadata metadata = new StorageMetadata.Builder()
                .setContentType("audio/mpeg")
                .build();
        UploadTask uploadTask = fileRef.putFile(fileUri, metadata);

        uploadTask.addOnProgressListener(taskSnapshot -> {
            long bytesTransferred = taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred();
            long totalBytes = taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount();
            int progress = (int) ((100.0 * bytesTransferred) / totalBytes);
            Log.i(TAG,""+progress);
            updateProgressNotification(progress);
        }).addOnSuccessListener(taskSnapshot -> {
            Log.d(TAG, "Upload successful");
            stopForeground(true);
            stopSelf();
        }).addOnFailureListener(exception -> {
            Log.e(TAG, "Upload failed: " + exception.getMessage());
            stopForeground(true);
            stopSelf();
        });
    }

    private Notification createNotification() {
        createNotificationChannel();

        return new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setContentTitle("Uploading...")
                .setContentText("Upload in progress")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.baseline_arrow_upward_24)
                .build();
    }

    private void createNotificationChannel() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            CharSequence name = "Upload Channel";
            String description = "Channel for upload progress notification";
            NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);
            channel.setDescription(description);

            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
    }

    private void updateProgressNotification(int progress) {
        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setContentTitle("Uploading...")
                .setContentText(progress + "% completed")
                .setProgress(100, progress, false)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.baseline_arrow_upward_24)
                .build();

        NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        notificationManager.notify(1, notification);
    }

    private void cancelProgressNotification() {
        NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        notificationManager.cancel(1);
    }
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}

And if I choose a file with audio picker and the upload process is successful, this is the result:
The file size on the firestore: 8.7 KB, while in the emulator: 5.06 MB
I tried to upload in physical device, but the result is same. The logcat write this message: Upload successful.
I try to upload a file, but the firebase doesn't get the file content. Please try to help me!

"the application doesn't upload the content" is really hard to help with, and Stack Overflow is a notoriously inefficient interactive debugger. I recommend debugging the problem case locally and telling us the result. If you set a breakpoint on each line of the code you shared, run the code in a debugger, and then check the value of each variable on each line, which is the first line that doesn't do what you expect it to do?

If you're new to this: the Android docs have a great page on debugging your app to get you started with, including the section on working with breakpoints and inspecting varialbles.

Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond using @.
